# Adding a <form action="" > issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

net and I have a question regarding what the proper syntax and requirements for

```
<form action="">
```

are

I am using visual studio express for web 2013 and following the asp.net MVC framework

Part of the requirements of this assignment are: "The method signature MUST have a parameter of type Manufacturer. This is a best practice."

I was looking at the example website's html form and this was the form tag:

```
<form action="/Manufacturers/addmanufacturer" method="post">
```

The form is in an index view in the Manufacturers folder, I have not yet added the 'addmanufacturer' yet because I am not sure what is required with it. Is that a controller? Is it just a code file? What item do I implement for the 'addmanufacturer'? I noticed that the 'addmanufacturer' does not have any sort of "." whatever following it

Another part that is required is "The method return value MUST redirect to the Index() method." Could that part be further elaborated on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, in ASP.NET MVC, you just use the [Html.BeginForm()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  // Form goodies go here
}
```

You'll see from the link that you can optionally specify the action, controller, route values, and html attributes.

EDIT: To handle the form, you'd create an action in the controller (same name for action and in the same controller unless you specify otherwise). If you use the POST method, you can decorate the action method with the [HttpPost] attribute to help the routing along.

Something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
}
```

You can alternatively create a strong type that would be automatically populated, known as a View Model.

Comment: me: oooooooooohhhh. Totally forgot my prof was talking about html helpers today in class. thanks for reminding me!

Comment: one more question: what would it be considered as a new item? a controller?

Comment: just a quick note that the url listed above for the post action will be `/Manufacturers/` and not `/Manufacturers/AddManufacturer` (as stated in the OP question)

Answer (score 1):

The `AddManufacturer` would be (typically) an `Action` on the `Manufacturers` controller. Just how the `Index` action is defined on the `Manufactures` controller.

Now I am not exactly sure what the quote:

> The method return value MUST redirect to the Index() method.

Is actually referring to, but what I imagine  (as I dont have the sample, or book). I am assuming that once you fill in the form and click submit it is `Posted` to the `AddManufacturer` action on the Manufacturers controller.

Now an action should typically result in an `ActionResult` (doesnt have to but typically does) so what I understand is that when the processing logic for the `AddManufacturer` action is complete it should redirect back to the `Index` action on the Manufacturers controller. This is typically (again not always) called a `RedirectToRouteResult` and in this example would be called such as:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

That code will instruct the browser to redirect back to the `Index` action on the `Manufacturers` controller.

As for your form, (based on your example) the html helper listed in another response will post to the `Index` action on the `Manufacturers` controller. However you wish to post to the `AddManufacturers` action you will need to use.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddManufacturers", "Manufacturers"))
{

}
```

I hope this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: I think, the other additional parameters in the url will be lost on form submit if you explicitly specify the controller & action methods in BeginForm

Comment: Which parameters? The querystring paramters? yes they will be, however the post will go to the correct controller. You can provide the additional routeValues if you wish.